# How to find $\operatorname{Im}(T), \ker T$ of $T: C^2[0,2\pi]\to C[0,2\pi] \quad Tf=f''+f$

Tags: linear-transformations

I'm trying to find  $\operatorname{Im}(T) , \operatorname{Ker}(T)$ of $T: C^2[0,2\pi]\to  C[0,2\pi] \quad Tf=f''+f$ where $  C^2[0,2\pi]$ is a second order differential continuous function on the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

What I thought was to solve $$\quad f(x)''+f(x)=0$$
which gives me as solution $$c_1*\sin(x)+ c_2*\cos(x)$$
So my first question is if I can express the kernel as:$$\operatorname{Ker}(T)= f\in C^2[0,2\pi]:f=\cos(x)+\sin(x)$$

Also I'm stuck on how to find  $\quad\operatorname{Im}(T)$, is it possible to express it as:
  $$\operatorname{Im}(T)=f(x)\in C[0,2\pi]$$

Comment: The kernel will be $every$ linear combination of sines and cosines restricted to $[0,2\pi]$. The image will be every $C^2$ function on $[0,2\pi]$, $g$,  that has a particular solution to $g=f+f''$, where $f$ also belongs to $C^2[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: What class is this? Or book are you using?

Comment: It's from a class of Linear Algebra, in this case the topic is linear transformations. So can I say $Im(T)=g,f \in C^2[0,\pi]:g=f''+f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel is the entire space spanned by $f(x)″+f(x)=0$, as you say, this is $c_1 \cdot \sin(x) + c_2 \cdot \cos(x)$, however you picked only one particular vector in this space (with $c_1 = c_2 = 1$.)  Notation-wise, I would write:

Ker$(T) = \{ c_1 \sin x + c_2 \cos x \}$, with $c_1, c_2 \in $R (or maybe C).

Thanks to the domain and range being the same, and since each Fourier component is an eigenvector of T we know that the image is the orthogonal complement of the kernel.

Comment: I don't fully understand the last part which you say each Fourier component is an eigenvector of T. What book or document can I read to understand why the image is the orthognal complement of the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little ill posed. If $f \in C^2[0,2 \pi]\setminus C^3[0,2 \pi]$, then $Tf $ is continuous. but not continuously differentiable (since
$f''$ is not continuously differentiable), hence it cannot be the case
that $T: C^2[0,2 \pi] \to C^2[0,2 \pi]$.

If $Tf = 0$ then $f$ satisfies $f''+f=0$ and hence $f$ is in the span of
$\sin, \cos$ which also solve the equation. Hence $\ker T = \operatorname{sp} \{ \cos, \sin \}$.

If we write $T: C^2[0,2 \pi] \to C[0,2 \pi]$ instead, then if $g$ is continuous, we can show that $f''+f=g$ has a ($C^2[0,2 \pi]$) solution, and
hence $T$ is surjective.